# Cant import firebase into react native

Tags: firebase, react-native

I must have gone through every page on google to try and solve this problem.

I am trying to simply import firebase into my react native app.
I have tried these following import statements but none of them work.

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

and 

import firebase from 'firebase/app';

and

import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";
```

All i get is an error telling me it cant find the module.
Can some please help.

Edit: here is package.json

```
{
  "name": "MubApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^6.0.2",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.4.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.4.4",
    "babel-jest": "24.8.0",
    "jest": "24.8.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.54.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: Add the package.json file, please.

Comment: Hi Suraj, I've updated my question to include package.json.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following two lines to import the libraries:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with theese:

- Clean build folder in XCode
- Restart XCode
- Relaunch the package manager
- Try updating you package.json

Sometimes when I get errors regarding modules, trying theese steps can help.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for your response. It turned out a system restarted sorted out the problems.